# package declaration error depending on the IDE used

Tags: java, eclipse, package

I have created a program with Dr.Java with the following package declaration:

- dir \program            -> package program:
- dir \program\model      -> package program.model;
- dir \program\view       -> package programa.view;
- dir \program\controller -> package program.controller;

Now, I've tried to import this project in Eclipse (using the same folder where the .class files are as root folder for the project) but it gives me errors like this one:

> The declared package "programa.model" does not match the expected package "model"

If I remove "program."  from the package declaration, it works in Eclipse but not in Dr.Java.

The reason why i want to use two IDEs is beacause i am working on two different computers. An old laptop where I use Dr.Java and another newer computer where i can use an IDE with more features (like Eclipse).

Could somebody tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which folder is your root folder? Seems like you are using `program` folder as root folder. It should be the parent folder of `program` folder.

Comment: You can add snapshot of folder structure for better clarity.

Comment: @cse Thank you. That was the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are using program folder as root folder. It should be the parent folder of program folder.

In following image of folder structure, you should use `JavaWorkspace` folder as root folder:

[image]